# INAR(1) simulation in R

Tags: r, simulation, monte-carlo, longitudinal-data-analysis, discrete-time

How do we simulate values of $Y_t$ for a maximum value of $t=60$ when we have an INAR(1) process as follows: 
 
$Y_t=ρ^*Y_{(t-1)}+R_t$
where  
 $t$ takes values from 1 to 60, 
  $ρ=0.3,0.8$,  
 $ρ^*$ is the thinning, 
 
$R_t$ is assumed to follow Poisson distribution with rate
$λ_t$ = $exp(β_0 +β_1x_{1t})$ where 
$β_0=β_1=1$
 
We are required to simulate values for a 100 Monte Carlo experiments.

Answer (score 1):

The [definition of the INAR(1) process](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/j.1467-9892.1987.tb00438.x) leads to a straightforward simulation implementation: if $$_=ρ\circ _{−1}+_$$
this means that$$_=\sum_{i=1}^{Y_{−1}}\zeta_{it}+_$$where
$$\zeta_{it}\stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal B(1,\rho)\qquad R_t\sim\cal P(\lambda_t)$$i.e.$$ρ\circ _{−1}\sim\mathcal B\text{in}(_{−1},\rho)$$Hence
the R code for simulating $Y_t$ given $Y_{t-1}$ and $\lambda_t$ could be

```
Y[t]=rbinom(1,Y[t-1],rho)+rpois(1,lambda[t])
```

Resulting in a graph like the following

[image]

where blue stands for the $y_t$'s and gold for the $x_t$'s

Comment: Is it mandatory to create a function for the variable $Y[t]$?

Comment: This is an R programming (and unclear) question, unrelated to the simulation and the forum.